# Sequel to Alfred Slote's Clone Catcher?

Tags: story-identification

*Clone Catcher* was a juvenile novel from the early 80s that dealt with the morality of clone harvesting. I thought it was pretty fun and had heard that there was a sequel once upon a time but have never been able to determine the veracity of the rumor. Was there such a sequel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found no mention of a sequel, and [none of his books](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/82445.Alfred_Slote) are either marked as a sequel or look like a likely one. He is still alive and has contact info on [his website](http://www.alfredslote.com/#!jake), so I sent an email off to the site in hopes of getting an answer.

Comment: Hunh. I didn't even find his website. Sounds great, can't wait to hear what he says.

Comment: Still no response, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm going to mark it as the answer anyway- you did the work and I'll accept it as the answer unless someone comes up with proof otherwise.